# Json Library for .Net Microframework

Tags: .net, json, .net-micro-framework, netduino

I'm running a light webserver using .Net Microframework and I was wondering what libraries would work well for for mainly JSON serialization, but possibly deserialization as well.

Problem I've found with a lot of JSON libraries is they use fancy .Net features not available in MF, and are more complicated then what I need.

I could easily write a simple library to accomplish my tasks but I was wondering if anything else was available.

Thanks

Comment: Did you end up writing your own library?

Answer (score 3):

There is a lightweight JSON parser in the NetduinoHelpers library that is specifically built to minimize footprint: http://netduinohelpers.codeplex.com/

Comment: Good stuff there, but as far as I see there is only a parser (deserializer) not a serializer.

Answer (score 3):

Mike Jones uploaded a **[JSON Serialization and Deserialization library](http://www.tinyclr.com/codeshare/search?q=%22json-serialization-and-deserialization-library%22)** for the .NET Micro Framework.

> This is a JSON (de)serialization library that can encode (nearly) any
> C# object into a JSON string, and back. It manages primitives (int,
> float, string), dates, objects (classes, arrays, dictionaries), and
> objects within objects (within objects, etc).
>
> ...
>
> I recall, it's about 13k in size, so it's kinda big, and kinda slow, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've tried [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) as it has solution files for Silverlight and WindowsPhone. The implication being that if it works in restricted environments like those it may work in the .NET Microframework.

Comment: I believe the problem with Json.NET is its heavy use of Regex which is (as yet) not supported in NETMF.