# .Net Micro with Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-micro-framework, netduino

I'm trying to make a Netduino communicate with Azure. I've found several other projects and in their source code they use the package Microsoft.WindowsAzure like any other Azure project. In my project, though, it claims that the package name cannot be resolved.

I found somewhere that I had to go into Manage NuGet Packages and install it, but when I try, it halts the installation at JSON and rolls it all back.

This is the error message I get:

```
Adding 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8' to Netduino.
Uninstalling 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETMicroFramework,Version=v4.2', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.
```

What haven't I done? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121915/json-library-for-net-microframework?rq=1)?

Comment: Yes, but NuGet still doesn't want to install the Azure package as I still don't have that specific Json installation.

Comment: Maybe you can add the resource like to 'what you found somewhere'

Comment: I don't know how to do that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NETMF.Json if you are running NETMF 4.2 or later
[NETMF.Json on GitHub](https://github.com/mweimer/Json.NetMF)

I use it in my realtime pub/sub client for NetDuino here [XSockets NetMF client](https://github.com/codeplanner/XSockets.NETMF.Client)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Newtonsoft.Json is not compatible with .NET Microframework

*"Supports .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, Silverlight, Windows Phone and Windows 8"* (from http://json.codeplex.com/ )

Infact you get this error:
You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETMicroFramework,Version=v4.2', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.